# Jsoup: get all elements before a certain element / remove all elements after a certain element

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Suppose I have html like this:

```
<div class="pets">
  <div class="pet">...</div>
  <div class="pet">...</div>
  <div class="pet">...</div>
  <div class="pet">...</div>
  <div class="friends-pets">Your friends have these pets:</div>
  <div class="pet">...</div>
  <div class="pet">...</div>
  <div class="pet">...</div>
  <div class="pet">...</div>
  <div class="pet">...</div>
  <div class="pet">...</div>
</div>
```

I want to only get `<div class="pet">` that come before `<div class="friends-pets">`. Is there a way to do it with Jsoup? I know I can get all pets like this:

```
Element petsWrapper = document.selectFirst(".pets");
Elements pets = petsWrapper.select(".pet");
```

but that would include the extra pets too. I was wondering if I could only select the above pets or just remove the below pets and then use that code?

Comment: Class `Elements` is inherited from `ArrayList`.

Comment: I encounter a similar problem with stacked elements https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66970726/jsoup-get-all-elements-before-a-certain-element-remove-all-stacked-elements-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation in comments:

```
Element petsWrapper = document.selectFirst(".pets");
Elements pets = petsWrapper.select(".pet");
// select middle element
Element middleElement = petsWrapper.selectFirst(".friends-pets");
// remove from "pets" every element that comes after the middle element
pets.removeAll(middleElement.nextElementSiblings());
System.out.println(pets);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a very simple way you can do it with a single selector:

```
.pet:not(.friends-pets ~ .pet)
```

This works by using the `:not()` [selector](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/select/Selector.html) with `.friends-pets ~ .pet` finding each div after the `.friends-pets` class. It then excludes those from the rest of the `.pet` class matches.

See an working online example here: [try.jsoup](https://try.jsoup.org/~2_07dYM3U1zQb1meD6wjtx59egg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna check out Krystian's answer, but having tried to solve this myself, I've come up with this one:

```
//get all divs
Elements divElements = doc.select("div");
//valid pet divs will be here
List<Element> pets = new ArrayList<>();
for (Element divElement: divElements)  {
    if (divElement.className().equalsIgnoreCase("friends-pets")) {
       //invalid div, the cycle stops here 
       break;
     }

     if (divElement.className().contains("pet"))  {
        //if there has been no invalid div so far, adding a pet
        pets.add(divElement);
     }
}
```

If you think there's something wrong with this answer, please let me know. If you have reasons for why I should use one of the current two answers over the other, please comment too!

Comment: Looks like another valid way to solve this problem. Still I'd go with the solution that requires 2 lines instead of iterating and checking conditions. Your answer may be more suitable in case when you want to check something more complicated, for example: `className().contains("xxx") || className().contains("yyy") && !className().contains("zzz") || className.matches("abc\\d\\dxyz")`